# Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

Tags: java

```
if(comando == "w"); {
    System.out.println("Você foi para o norte.");
    System.out.println("Um inimigo surgiu!!! Oque deseja fazer? (a = atacar e f = fugir)");
    comando = in.nextLine();
    if(comando == "a"); {
        if(rand.nextInt(100) < 75) {
            System.out.println("Você acertou o inimigo, você venceu!");             
            } else {                    
            System.out.println("Você errou o inimigo, você perdeu !");                                                              
         } 
       } else {
            System.out.println("Você correu o jogo acabou!"
```

Fiz esse comando, mas ele não funciona devido a um erro de syntax, estou a um tempo resolver.

Comment: Esse ponto-e-vírgula depois do `if` era para existir mesmo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está no primeiro `if`... Tem um `;` ali que não deveria existir